# How to pass data from an installer class to the OnStart() method of a windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, setup-project

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class AttendanceInstaller : Installer
{
   public string idString;
   public string hoursString;
 
   public AttendanceInstaller()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
   
   public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   {
      base.Install(stateSaver);
      idString = Context.Parameters["DeviceID"];
      hoursString = Context.Parameters["Hours"];
    }    
}

    
public partial class Attendance : ServiceBase
{
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
   
   }
}
```

I need to use `idString` variable of the `AttendanceInstaller` class in the `onStart()` method. How can I do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless this is a trick question, the answer is: By passing the respective data into `OnStart`. It's unclear what your specific issue is.

Comment: I'm sorry for this.
I have two files each with a class. I tried to use a get() method that returned the variable, but the value is always empty. I can't pass the value of those variables outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the risk of writing an answer but providing no solution. I believe what you are trying is not possible. At least, in an immediate sense. Your class AttendanceInstaller inherits from Installer. The Installer class is used to install the service. It may get executed once.
Your  class Attendance inherits from ServiceBase. It implements a service by overriding the OnStart method. The OnStart method is called when the service is started through the Service Control Manager. So you have two separated classes (intances if being purist) that may never share scope. So you should find an alternative way of passing data, perhaps with a file on disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I feared in fact. I solved it by adding the variables to the app.exe.config file in the AttendanceInstaller class and then reading them in the onStart () method.